# Show that $0$ is the only limit point of the set $A=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I've trying to prove the next statement: If $$A=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ show that $A'=\{0\}$ on $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ as a metric space. I've already shown that $\{0\}\subset A'$ but I can't prove that if $0<x<1$ then $x\notin A'$. The remmaining cases are done $(x<0,x\geq 1$). Any hint or help?

Comment: You wrote $\{0\}\subset A'$ but what about the title of your post?

Comment: sorry, I have always trouble for the titles, yes... thanks.

Comment: Maybe the title is, Show that $0$ is the only limit point.

Comment: Notation clarification: $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$ refers to the Euclidean metric?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already showed that $0\in A'$. Suppose $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $x\neq 0$. The case $x<0$ or $x\geq 1$ is easy to handle. Lets take at the case (where you got a problem) where $0<x<1$. Suppose that $x\in A$. Then $x=\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$. We take $G=\bigg(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n-1}\bigg)$. In here, 
$$G\cap A=\{x\}.$$ Thus, $x\notin A'$. Suppose that $x\notin A$. Then $\frac{1}{x}\notin \Bbb N$. Thus, there exist $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n<\frac{1}{x}<n+1$, that is, $\frac{1}{n}>x>\frac{1}{n+1}$. So, we take $G=\bigg(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\bigg)$. In this case, $$G\cap A=\emptyset.$$ Hence, $x\notin A'$.

Answer (score 2):

Choose the smallest $N$ such that $1/N<x$. In just one more step, you can totally come up with an open set that contains $x$ but no point in $A$.